# Revert local app to old commit, push it and replace commits further down branch

Tags: git, github

So I am on a branch with a bunch of commits. At a certain point in time I decide that the most recent commit is bad and I want to go back to the second-to-last commit. I did this using `git reset --hard xxxxxxxxxx`, where xxxxxxxxxx is the first ten digits of the commit code. This seems to work fine for reverting my local app to the conditions of the second-to-last commit.

However, when I try and `add`, `commit`, and `push` changes, I get an error that the tip of my local branch is behind its remote counterpart. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Git will only allow you to change *new* commits to a remote repository, i.e. commits that only add to what the remote already has. This is mainly to make sure that everybody working with the repository stays in a consistent state and their repositories won’t break.

If you knowingly want to remove the commit from your remote, you can use `git push --force` to *overwrite* what the remote has and force it to accept whatever you give it. This is what you want to do to actually remove a commit from a remote. Note again that this actually breaks the local repositories of everyone else involved (just like rebasing), so don’t do it unless you are either the only one working with it, or you actually agreed with everyone on this.

The saner way to undo the changes is by doing a *revert*. That is an additional commit that undoes the work that has been previously done. So instead of removing a commit from the history, you add another commit that undoes the commit. You can do that using `git revert commit-you-want-to-revert`.

Answer (score 0):

Your local branch is behind its remote counterpart for either 1 or 2 reasons:

1. Your branch is shared, and someone pushed additional changes to the remote that you have to pull and sync your local branch with before git will let you push your changes, or
2. You pushed your most recent commit to the remote, so git won't just let you push non-fast-forward changes, because that will overwrite that commit. In this case, overwriting the commit is probably what you want, since you threw it away locally, so you can force push in this case.